# I have a title after a youtube iframe, and the title is at the right of the iframe, why?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I have a youtube iframe in html and a title after the iframe, such as for example:

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" width="200" height="162" align="left"></iframe>

<H4 id="example_video">Example with a video</H4>
```

But the title is the the same line as the video. Why? I could not change that even by using `display: block` in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said `align="left"` which is an obsolete way of setting `float: left`.

Remove it.

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" width="200" height="162"></iframe>

<H4 id="example_video">Example with a video</H4>
```